# How to send a POST request to spring mvc application with Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I created a controller like this.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User login(@RequestBody final User user) {
        return user;
    }

}
```

When I send a request with bash:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/mvc/login.do {"id":null,"name":null,"password":null}%
```

It works well.

But I got a error `POST http://localhost:8080/mvc/login.do 415 (Unsupported Media Type)`, when I sent a request like this.

```
$.ajax({  method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify("{
            'id': 'test,
            'name': 'test1'
        }"),
        url:"login.do",
        timeout: 60000,
        success: sign_submited,
        error: ajaxError
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try to set content type in your ajax request as--       `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",`